# HTML on body load run a href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML Link:

```
<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">Fade and Pop</a>
```

that uses jquery to bring up a popup box.

how can i make the box appear on body load?

here is the full jquery code:

```
(function($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

    $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
    });

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {


        var defaults = {  
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        }; 

        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/
            var modal = $(this),
                topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
                topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
                locked = false,
                modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/
            if(modalBG.length == 0) {
                modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
            }           

/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/
            //Entrance Animations
            modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
              modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
                $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
                if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    }
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    } 
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                        unlockModal()               
                    }
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:open');
            });     

            //Closing Animation
            modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
              if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                            modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                    }       
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:close');
            });     

/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/
            //Open Modal Immediately
        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

            //Close Modal Listeners
            var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });

            if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
                modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
                modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                  modal.trigger('reveal:close')
                });
            }
            $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
            });


/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/
            function unlockModal() { 
                locked = false;
            }
            function lockModal() {
                locked = true;
            }   

        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: On a side note, what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').click(); or $('#myModal').reveal(); will do this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the click event for the link, or just execute the bound function for click(`$('#myModal').reveal();` in your case if no other data attributes exist for the given link).